# Display an Image attachment in XPages via a Java Bean

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino

I have a public facing application that is architected with multiple nsfs. I have one nsf that's public facing that manages data through Java controllers in the non-public facing nsfs. For security reasons the non-public nsfs do not allow URL browsing so I can't use the usual "/0/" + UNID + "/$FILE/" + PhotoFilename to display the image on the XPage.

In the controller I can get the attachment (EmbeddedObject) from the document, but I'm not sure how to get it to display in an <xp:image> or <xp:inputRichText> control.

I am using the OpenNTF api, but I can't see anything there that seems to help.

Thanks,
Scott.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution: base64 encode the image and use the encoded string in an img tag. Here's a simple code example that uses the inputstream from the EmbeddedObject in a method in a Java controller:

```
public String getImageAsBase64(InputStream inputStream) {
    return Base64.encodeBytes(IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream));
}
```

You can then display the base64 encoded image (assuming your Java controller is called 'controller'):

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,#{javascript:controller.getImageAsBase64()}" />
```

Comment: Thanks Per. It worked like a charm. I'll just need to modify the image/jpg to support image/png and image/gif as the users will have the ability to upload those image types as well. I'll probably just change the controller call to getImageSource() and include the data and encoded image string. Thanks again.